# Splitting wire to LED strip?

Tags: led

I have plain white LED strips under 3 of the cabinets in the kitchen of my newly purchased house with separate low voltage wires coming out of the wall leading to a connector on each of them. The lighting is good except for over the sink, where there is not a strip. I was thinking I would run a strip under the window sill over the sink, then connect the wire from the new strip to the wire that leads to a strip under one of the cabinets. But in researching, I can't find an answer if splitting the power to the old strip would be OK. I can't find the transformer that is being used (maybe in the wall?) so I don't know its power rating. It must be hardwired from a dimmable light switch in the kitchen. Does anyone know or think it would be OK to cut and split the wire?

Comment: You'll have to find out wattage data on the existing strips, your new strip, and the transformer for anyone to have a hope of answering your question....

Answer (score 1):

The answer with the information provided is no it would not be safe. First you would need to know the voltage and wattage already on the line and the capability of the power supply. If the supply is encased in a wall without access this would be a code violation in the US under the NEC. Finding the transformers would be my first goal.